# How do we need to apply the martingale convergence theorem here?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, martingales, probability-limit-theorems

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a measure space
- $E_0\in\mathcal E$ with $\mu(E_0)\in(0,\infty)$
- $n\in\mathbb N$
- $B_1,\ldots,B_n\subseteq\left.\mathcal E\right|_{E_0}:=\left\{B\cap E_0:B\in\mathcal E\right\}$ be disjoint with $$\biguplus_{i=1}^n=E_0\tag1$$
- $f:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$c:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\in(0,\infty)$$ and $$\nu:=\frac1cf\mu$$

> I would like to show that $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{\mu(B_i)}\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}\mu\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac1{\mu(E_0)}\int_{E_0}f\:{\rm d}\mu.\tag2$$

As [kimchi lover](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/457779/kimchi-lover) noted, there might be a probabilistic proof available utilizing the [martingale convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob's_martingale_convergence_theorems). Obviously, $$\operatorname E_\nu\left[f\mid B\right]=\frac1{\mu(B_i)}\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}\mu\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal E.\tag3$$ Now, I guess we consider the filtration $\mathcal F_1,\ldots,F_n$ where $\mathcal F_i$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ generated by $B_1\uplus\cdots\uplus B_i$. We should obtain $$\operatorname E_\nu\left[f\mid\mathcal F_j\right]=\operatorname E_\nu\left[f\mid B_i\right]\;\;\;\text{almost surely on}B_i\tag4$$ for all $1\le i\le j\le n$.

> However, I'm still struggling how we can conclude.

Comment: @kimchilover Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @kimchilover I'm using standard notation. So, could you please tell me what of it is hard to understand? Since there is no (super-)martingale in the question, I don't see how the martingale convergence theorem is relevant here. Could you clarify why you think it is related?

Comment: @kimchilover $\mathcal E_0$ is a subset of $\left.\mathcal E\right|_{E_0}$, where $\left.\mathcal E\right|_{E_0}:=\left\{B\cap E_0:B\in\mathcal E\right\}$ denotes the trace $\sigma$-algebra. For the rest of your comment: I know the martingale convergence theorem. I cannot tell you why it doesn't solve my problem, cause I don't see how it is even related to it. $f_0$ is supposed to be the [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) of $f$ over $E_0$.

Comment: I give up.  Sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: @kimchilover Maybe you could start to be less offensive. Obviously you look from a different side onto the problem and I struggle to follow your thoughts. I see that $f_0=\operatorname E_\nu\left[f\mid E_0\right]$, but I don't get why the martingale convergence theorem helps here. Where is the martingale? Maybe you could explain it.

Comment: @kimchilover Okay, I start to get the feeling that you're right. I've completely updated the question such that it should be clearer what I'm asking now. I'm still struggling how we can conclude. Maybe you can take a look.

Comment: Do we have finitely many $B_1, B_2,\ldots, B_n$ only or countably many pairwisely disjoint sets? I notice that $E_0$ is the disjoint union of $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ at the very beginning and $n$ being fixed. However, we let $n\rightarrow\infty$ later.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan We ony have finitely many ($n$). I'm asking for what happens if the subdivision of $E_0$ becomes finer and finer (which is the case as $n\to\infty$).

Comment: @0xbadf00d For clarity, it is better to denote those $B_i$ using double index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general.

Notation: for each $n$, we make a partition $\{B_n^j\}_{j=1}^m $ of $E_0$ into $m$ cells, where $B_n^j$ is the jth cell in the nth partition.

Let $E_0=[0,1]$ and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be the indicator function for $[1/2,1]$ (or a smooth approximation thereof). At stage $n$, let $B_n^m = [1/2,1]$ and let $B_n^1$ through $B_n^{m-1}$ be some partition of $[0,1/2)$ where each cell has positive measure. Then, $\mu(E_0)^{-1} \int_{E_0} f d\mu = 1/2$, but $$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{\mu(B_n^j)}\int_{B_n^j}fd\mu=\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{\mu(B_n^m)}\int_{B_n^m}fd\mu=\frac{1}{m}\longrightarrow 0.$$

Addendum: of course, the reason why you might expect your statement to hold is our intuition from when we divide $E_0$ into cells which are all equal size. But in this case the result holds true at every stage (not just in the limit), since $\mu(B_n^j)=\frac{\mu(E_0)}{m}$ and a convenient cancellation occurs.

However! There is a very similar problem, basically the dual to your stated problem, where you *can* use martingale techniques. If you have a filtration of partitions (say, countable at each stage) that get coarser and coarser so that in in the limit the partition is just ${\{\emptyset,E_0\}}$, then the conditional expectations with respect to this filtration form a *reverse martingale*, and one can apply Lévy's Downwards Theorem (14.4 in Williams' Probability with Martingales) to show that this sequence of conditional expectations converges in the limit to the average on $E_0$ (pointwise almost surely - remember, the conditional expectation is understood as a random variable).

This is not precisely the analogue of your question, where you take an unweighted average of the conditional expectations in each cell, but it is nearby enough that I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem I'm actually trying to solve is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3221016/47771. Maybe you can help there too?